# How to call flask migrate api in script

Tags: python, alembic, flask-migrate

I have a database `db`. I want to judge if `flask_migrate` has created tables in `db`. If not, `upgrade db`.
There are commands, but no examples about calling `migrate`, `upgrade` in python script.
The test files in `flask_migrate` also run commands:

```
(o, e, s) = run_cmd('python app.py db migrate')
```

Comment: Did you see the [API reference](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#api-reference) section of the documentation?

Comment: Yes, but still don't know how to call them

Comment: Yes, I got it. just need to specify the 'migrations' dir

Answer (score 8):

This should do the trick for you.

```
from flask_migrate import upgrade


@ns.route('/migrate_db')
class Units(Resource):
    def get(self):
        upgrade(directory=<path_to_migrations_folder>)
```